# Still need to sudo after switching to root user

Tags: linux, unix, sudo

I switch to root user like so:

```
$ sudo su -
```

And then I try to run something like `birdc`

```
[root@localhost ~]# birdc
Unable to connect to server control socket (/usr/local/var/run/bird.ctl): 
No such file or directory
```

I find that I still need to `sudo` to run commands like the one above:

```
[root@localhost ~]# sudo birdc
BIRD 1.4.2 ready.
bird>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this something to do with the way I have installed BIRD?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour. I've used vanilla ubuntu 12.04 for my test. Your path `/usr/local/var/run/bird.ctl` looks like you've installed it manually from source code. Can you show the output of `ls -al /usr/local/var/run/bird.ctl` ?

Comment: Probably better to `sudo -s` to open a root shell.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin I'll do that in future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There appears to be something wrong with your root login scripts.  As a test, try doing `sudo su` without the `-`. This will change users without creating a login shell.

To figure out what your root login scripts are doing, run

```
printenv > /tmp/before
sudo su -
printenv > /tmp/after
diff /tmp/before /tmp/after
```

and then do the same thing again from a new user shell, but without the `-` arg to `su`. I bet you will see something.

However every program on a Linux system should be able to run with a root login shell.  You need to configure your system in a way that it works with both `su` and `su -`. Meaning settings paths and permissions the right way. Have a look on a vanilla Ubuntu for example. It will work with `su` and `su -`

Comment: And how should this help here?

Comment: @marflar If it fixes something for you, it means you installed it wrong because it means you can't login as root and use `birdc`. I think both answers are misleading.

Comment: that experiment could have saved me a lot of headache in many situations... +1

Comment: @Mark Do you really think it is ok that a program on Linux can't be started from a root login shell? The real solution here is to fix file permissions and paths in a way that it works **with** `su -`. I told that with a vanilla ubuntu this problem does not happen. It happens because the OP has misconfigured his system. Now, after getting such tipps the situation will get event worst. Good job you did. Good job the 4 up-voters did! -1 from my side.

Comment: I do not agree entirely @hek2mgl. It is true that the real solution to the underlying problem could be what you say, and things should be sorted out so it works that way (both with and without `su`). However, @marflar wanted to know **what** was the actual difference that caused this situation. The experiment proposed by @Mark is good to see that. In the end, they probably should try to make it run both ways, but it's way more difficult if you do not actually know what's the difference.

Comment: @cnluzon Thx for your response. Yes and no. While I'm with you that the OP might not being aware of the difference between `su` and `su -` I still think the conclusion and suggestion is wrong (or did not happen). You can be 99% sure, that the OP - if he does not reflect the answer - will now starting to teach others (and himself): "Don't use su -, it's evil". And you see that OP is actually not able to reflect that. That's why I told "good job". And that's why I still think my down-votes are valid here. (I do that really rarely)

Comment: @hek2mgl I get what you say. Maybe then I would say "hey, you can see what's the difference in the environment with this trick **but** you should check for a misconfiguration in your system, because in a properly running linux your program **must** run properly also as `su`". Right?

Comment: @cnluzon Yes, then it would be an up-vote ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl - I see your point.The answer has been updated

Comment: @MarkLakata Looks better now ;) +1

Answer (score 2):

It might have to do with your `PATH` or some other environment variables. When you do `sudo`, the environment configuration you have as your username stays. However, when you do `su -` and login as root, the environment configuration changes.

But(!) every program on a Linux system should be able to run with a root login shell.  You need to configure your system in a way that it works with both `su` and `su -`. Meaning settings paths and permissions the right way. Have a look on a vanilla Ubuntu for example. It will work with `su` and `su -`

Comment: +1 for showing that OP should fix his system instead of using a "quickfix" :)